# Flask - Dynamically add a Form section

Tags: flask, webforms, forms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to figure out the multi-form input in html, [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnS4k.png)

Below is my question :

When I click "Add one more section", I want to have same web-form input as new section. Please help me out in this.

Thank you.

I'm using Flask-html

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
            <label for="JIRA">JIRA ticket</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="JIRA" placeholder="JIRA ticket">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
            <label for="Assignee">Assignee</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Assignee" placeholder="Assignee">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-7">
            <label for="Issue">Issue</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Issue" placeholder="Issue">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-9">
            <label for="Description">Description</label>
            <textarea name="Description" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" required></textarea>
        </div>
           <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label for="Comments">Comments</label>
            <textarea name="Comments" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments" required></textarea>
        </div>
             <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
            <label for="Status">Status</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Status" placeholder="In-progress or Resolved">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset"/>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Add one more section"/>
            </div>
    </form>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <br /><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement some AJAX in your .js file. When you click the add button, another form will be appended on to the existing one.

```
function addsectionFunction() {
var csrftoken = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
        }
    }
})

$.ajax({
    url: '/add-section',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#the-formdiv-id').append(data);
    }
});
};
```

Add Section HTML button.
`<button onClick="addsectionFunction();">Add One More Section</button>`

The `'/add-section'` view could be something like:

```
@app.route('/add-section', methods=['GET', 'POST')
def add_section():
    return render_template('new-section.html')
```

Comment: Hi Roy, Thanks for your input on this request. I have achieved my request with dynamic textbox creation using jquery as you mentioned. 

But right now, I m unable to redirect the dynamic text box's input to another html page. can you help me on this.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Hi Roy, currently issue is unable to redirect form inputs to another HTML page. However, I figured out redirecting inputs to another HTML page but able to fetch values of first row of inputs and not the input values created dynamic